# routes.php and controllers (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have two controllers
1- site
2- management

the first controllers(Site) is work successfuly
the second controllers(Managemnt) is not work.

I don't know what is the errror

I change the routes.php but still doesn't work(managment)

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
$route['Administration'] = "Administration/index";
$route['Administration/([a-z])'] = 'Administration/$1';
```

this links work:

> example.com/hotel/12312
>
> example.com/contact
>
> example.com/city/newyork
>
> example.com/Administration

but this links doesn't works:

> example.com/Administration/hotels
>
> example.com/Administration/add_new
>
> example.com/Administration/cities

where is the problem pls because I tired to solve this problem

thaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the order in witch you are giving route directives. 
Code igniter routes requests from top to bottom, so if you want your $route['Administration'] to precede $route['(:any)'] you have to set it first.

> ```
> $route['default_controller'] = "site";
> $route['Administration/([a-z])'] = 'Administration/$1';
> $route['Administration'] = "Administration/index";
> $route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
> ```

I would allways sugest putting (:any) routes at the end so they don't overwrite more specific routes.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with case sensitive controller names. try user lowercase on the routes definition.

$route['administration/([a-z])']
$route['administration']

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem & I get this working:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['([a-z-A-Z1-9_]+)'] = "site";
$route['management']="management";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

it may help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Codeigniter routing, but to me looks like everything is matching `$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";` before it ever reaches your Administration routes. Try moving it below everything else...you might also have to switch your Administration routes for the `([a-z])` to match

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['Administration/([a-z])'] = 'Administration/$1';
$route['Administration'] = "Administration/index";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/$1";
```